# Magento - Image next to top Categories name

Tags: php, html, css, magento, categories

I would like to display a small image next to my top navigation menu's names (i.e. category names).

So I want something like

```
Category1Name  small_img |  Category2Name small_img2 | Category3Name small_img3
```

Cheers

EDIT: Here's d HTML code using FIREBUG for my first category name

```
 <div class="nav-container">
   <ul id="nav">
     <li class="level0 nav-1 level-top first parent">
        <a class="level-top" href="http://localhost:8888/devats/index.php/ribbons-for-craft.html">
           <span>RIBBONS FOR CRAFT</span>
     <li class="level0 nav-2 level-top parent">
         <a class="level-top" href="http://localhost:8888/devats/index.php/ribbons-for-decoration.html">
            <span>RIBBONS FOR DECORATION</span>
             .
             .
             .
           n so on for my rest of the categories.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cand add category id to class then modify this classes via css.

Create a folder under app/code/local/Artlantis/Catalog/Block ( Artlantis is Namespace, replace with yours ) and put Navigation.php from app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block to newly created folder.

Change the Navigation.php as follows :

**Before :**

```
# find _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml method
    $htmlLi .= '>';
    $html[] = $htmlLi;

    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
```

**After :**

```
    $htmlLi .= '>';
    $html[] = $htmlLi;

    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span class="category_'.$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId().'">'.$this->escapeHtml($category->getName()).'</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
```

Add Artlantis_Catalog.xml in /app/etc/modules folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
  <Artlantis_Catalog>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
  </Artlantis_Catalog>
 </modules>
 </config>
```

add class in styles.css, for instance, if your catalog id 5 ( of course you should modify css )

```
.category_5 {
   background: url(../images/category_5_icon.png) no-repeat transparent;
}
```

PS : In case of any trouble, please post HTML output from Firebug, not default code, modified output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did as u instructed but I still can't see an image next to my category name. My first category name is **Ribbons for Decoration** , **Ribbons for Craft** and so on. So how would I name them in styles.css?

Comment: To make investigate, use Firebug, go to category names then paste HTML code in here.

Comment: I just realized that to use category name into class is a bad idea, maybe we can use category id instead of name, like cats_1, cats_2 etc. I will modify snippet after you paste the HTML code.

Comment: I am sorry but it still doesn't display the image. N using firebug too, it doesn't display my modified piece of code n shows the same default code. I know my code's getting saved but its just not applying to category name.